# Just starting. Have need of just printing some calculated numbers to the screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Good day all. Old time C programmer, new to both Java and Android. Sorry. Trying.
I have AIDE and Eclipse and a stack of tutorials that I am wading through. All seem to jump way ahead of some basic tools, that I need to use and understand.
Specifically: I simply want to have the app do some calculations on input from user, then display the numbers. In older times, I would use something like:

System.out.println("|" + y + "| is " + Math.abs(y));

I have found out how to use :
        ...
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello, Android");
        setContentView(tv);
        ...
but this does not allow for numbers.

Additionally, I have not yet found out how to use the XML portion to allow for dynamic text or numbers. E.g., each of the examples pre-codes a fixed text / string to display, but I need to create the text / string in the code then display it.
An example of code would be great, or just a pointer to a document. I really don't want to take too much of your time. Thanks in advance. Al

Comment: (1) post your code, (2) ask a specific question, (3) identify a specific problem. There are a number of things that could go wrong here...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean, "*does not allow for numbers*". No, you cannot directly pass an `int` into it, but you can do this:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
String text = "|" + y + "| is " + Math.abs(y);
tv.setText(text);
setContentView(tv);
```

Additionally, let's say you have a `TextView` in your `main.xml` file, such as:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="100px" />
```

Then, if you add `android:id="@+id/some_new_id"` to its parameters, you can reference this `TextView` through code.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_new_id);
```

And from there, you can perform any operations you want on it, which are updated in real-time from the UI thread.

The Android docs are great, you can read about [declaring layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html), which also covers editing these through code. (There are a couple broken links on that doc due to the redesign, but most are working, and Google should provide the rest you need!)

The Android developer path is a great one, hope you enjoy it!

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Soxxeh's answer, if you want to take user input and preform mathematical equations on it you will need  an EditText field:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />
```

You can than use this in code by doing the following:

```
EditText number= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_number);
String stringmunber= number.getText().toString();       
float floatnumber= Float.parseFloat(stringnumber);
```

Next preform mathematics:

```
float answer= number * number2; //number 2 is another edittext field
```

Now output it:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_new_id);
tv.setText(Float.toString(answer));
```

Hope this helps!